# Yield does not resolve Promise node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have the following code and although in this example there is nothing asynchronous I wrote it to understand the flow using generators and promises.

My goal is to loop through the array and execute an asynchronous process for every single item in the array and I want to do it in order. From what I've read I was expecting that the `yield operator(rule);` would yield the value of the resolved promise. Instead of the value `false` it gives me a Promise like the following `Promise { false }`

I think that I am missing/misunderstood something important in this flow.

Here's is the code:

```
'use strict';

let operator = function (rule) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(rule.bool);
    });
};

let setOfRule = [
    {
        name: 'one',
        bool: false
    },
    {
        name: 'two',
        bool: false
    },
    {
        name: 'three',
        bool: false
    }
];

let myGen = function* (rules) {
    for (let rule of rules) {
        try {
            yield operator(rule);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
};

for (let filtered of myGen(setOfRule)) {
    console.log(filtered); // Promise { false }
    console.log(`Is it filtered: ${filtered}`); // Is it filtered: [object Object]

    if (filtered) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `yield` and generators are synchronous. Promises are asynchronous. You can't force an async Promise to run synchronously just by returning it from a generator function. You should look into a library like [co](https://github.com/tj/co) for this.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently, I was under the impression that yield will wait until the promise is resolved. I 'll keep on reading on the subject.

@waza007 I know async and I've used it a lot, but I wanted to understand the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this nice article and a nice piece of code here
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Instead of trying to iterate through my generator X times and fetch the value. I am iterating through the values and yield the promise in every iteration. The on resolve it resolves the promise with the next method of my iterable otherwise it rejects with a throw error.

Here's is the working code:

```
'use strict';

let operator = function (rule) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(rule.bool);
    });
};

let setOfRule = [
    {
        name: 'one',
        bool: false
    },
    {
        name: 'two',
        bool: false
    },
    {
        name: 'three',
        bool: false
    }
];

let spawn = function spawn(generatorFunc) {
    function continuer(verb, arg) {
        let result;
        try {
            result = generator[verb](arg);
        } catch (err) {
            return Promise.reject(err);
        }

        if (result.done) {
            return result.value;
        } else {
            return Promise.resolve(result.value).then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
        }
    }

    let generator = generatorFunc();
    let onFulfilled = continuer.bind(continuer, 'next');
    let onRejected = continuer.bind(continuer, 'throw');

    return onFulfilled();
}

spawn(function *() {
    try {
        for (let rule of setOfRule) {
            let something = yield operator(rule);

            console.log(something);
        }

        console.log('Done!!!!');
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error: ', err);
    }
});
```